# how to implement a listener in web.xml?

Tags: servlet-listeners

i'm having problems trying to create a listener in my primefaces web aplication.
I have to differents web aplications both are in different servers, in aplication A I inserted the welcome page of aplication B, because the user need to create an order. When the order is finished aplication B must send an action to aplication A so i can close that external page and redirect to aplication A. 
Do you have any idea how can i do that?
Thanks.

Comment: it is a broad question, you need to narrow it down to a specific problem so people would spend their time to look at it

Comment: And it is in no way a PrimeFaces issue